# How do I create a reusable dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I'm after creating a really simple drop-down list, which essentially shows various times, and their value is the minutes past midnight for each time. For example:

```
Value       Time
60          01:00 AM
75          01:15 PM
90          01:30 PM
105         01:45 PM
120         02:00 PM
```

etc

The thing is, I need to use the same drop-down list in a whole bunch of views and controllers in my application. After reading a couple of articles, it seems like I need to create a static class for this? But all the examples seem to be way more complicated than I actually need. Is it an `IList` that I should be creating for this?

Comment: are you using any IoC in your mvc implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following method

1. Create a static class that generate data source for the dropdown

```cs
public static class DropdownData
{
    public static IList<SelectListItem> GetTimeList(string defaultValue)
    {
        var times = new List<SelectListItem>();
        times = Enumerable.Range(4, 4).Select(x => {
            var minute = x * 15;
            var time = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(minute);
            return new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = minute.ToString(),
                Text = time.ToString("hh:mm tt"),
                Selected = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue) && minute.Equal(defaultValue))
            };
        }).ToList();
        return times;
    }
}
```

2. In your views, you could create dropdown list with data source that generated  in step 1

```cs
@Html.DropDownList("TimeList", DropdownData.GetTimeList("75"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: This works perfect! How do I change is to list every 15-minute interval in 24 hours? Just change the range?

Comment: You could change to Enumerable.Range(**1, 96**) (24 hours = 96 times of 15 minutes)

Comment: Thanks @Trung. I don't suppose you know how i can select a default value using this approach. Is it possible? Should i be selecting the default value in the view, or in the construction of the list?

Comment: Where do i pass in that 'defaultValue' though?

Comment: You could pass it in your view, example call *DropdownData.GetTimeList("75")* will generate dropdown with second item be selected.

Comment: Yes, i tried that, but it doesn't work. It keeps default back to the first item in the list (which for me is now 12:00 AM or value '0'. Should it not be looking for an int instead of a string? Aren't all the values in the list of type int?

Comment: I've sorted it now, i needed to convert defaultValue string to an int, so that it matched the values in the list. Thanks for all your assistance

Answer (score 0):

If you need a value to be `Global`, then yes, you'll want it to be `public static` in C#.  I recommend also putting it in a `public static class` so you can access it by name.

```
public static class MyData
{
     public static IEnumerable<DateTime> ValueTimes { get; set;} //(or IList or List<T> or whatever you want)     
}

public class IDoStuff
{
  public DateTime myTime { get; set; }
  public IDoStuff(DateTime d) //constructor
  {
     if(ValueTimes.IndexOf(d) != -1) //-1 says I no findie
        myTime = d;
     else
        throw new ApplicationException("That's not a valid time, dummy");
  }
}
```

See, easy peasy.  Also, use `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`, even if it's all in the same day.  Don't use `strings` to represent time, you're asking for trouble that way.

Edit: While I was putting up the solution, you posted sample data.  Given this:

```
Value       Time
60          01:00 AM
75          01:15 PM
90          01:30 PM
105         01:45 PM
120         02:00 PM
```

I think you can actually just do this and skip the static variable:

```
public static Timespan GetTime(int value)
{
   return Timespan.FromMinutes(value);

}
```

Comment: Another option would be to add this to a base Controller class and have all your controllers inherit from this base class, or to use a Cache or other middle layer to store this (like HttpCache or Redis). This avoids using static variables in web code which makes me feel dirty :)